# using only Quaternions, How do I determine if my phone is in a "Dumping" position

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, air-native-extension, quaternions

A simple question really but I haven't come across it anywhere. I have an app that needs to allow the user to "dump" the contents. Basically this means any time the top of the phone is lower than the bottom of the phone (not upside down). I can grab the quaternion rotation of the phone off the gyroscope, but how do I know if the top of the phone is lower than the bottom

Answer (score 0):

This is a very interesting question.
I'm not completely sure of how to do this, but I think that if you rotate the 'up vector' (negative gravity direction) by the quaternion then check its z component sign, this may give you an indication.

Psuedocode:

```
g = [0 0 -1] // the direction of gravity (unit vector)
G = [0 g] // this is a pure quaternion
V = q* G q // Using quaternion multiplication
v = V[1:4] // extract last 3 components from pure Quat 
if (v[2] < 0.00) // Check the sign of the z component
  isFaceDown = true
```

I think this will work, although I suspect the more proper way is to map the quaternion to the surface of a sphere. If you cant get an answer you should ask on the mathematics stackexchange.